Line chart not displaying markers
I have two apexcharts in my webapp, both of which have a data series as well as a regression line series. One works perfectly, rendering the data series markers, as well as the regression line. The other will render the regression line, but not the data series. If I set the data series to type='line' type instead of type='scatter' it will render the line, but it will not render the markers for the line (otherwise I would just set the stroke to 0 and the marker size to 5 or something like that). I have spent several days searching and working with chatGPT to try to solve the mystery here. Below is the code that isn't working (LossChart.vue) as well as the code that is working (TackingImprovement.vue). Thank you in advance for your help!
LossChart.vue
<template>
    <div class="center" v-if="this.tag_metrics.length > 0" >
        <h4 class="is-size-4">{{ this.segment_names[this.tag] }}</h4>
        <div class="chart-container">
            <apexchart type="line" :options="chartOptions" :series="chartSeries">
            </apexchart>
        </div>

        <div class="select">
        <select v-model="metric">
            <option v-for="metric in metrics" v-bind:key="metric.value" v-bind:value="metric.value">
                {{ metric.text }}
            </option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <br />
        <p>{{this.metric_text}} explains {{r2Score}} of the variation in maneuver loss for {{this.segment_names[this.tag].toLowerCase()}}.</p>
        <p v-if="this.correlated">
            As {{this.metric_text}} increases, maneuver loss {{this.regDirection}}.
        </p>
        <br v-else />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import VueApexCharts from 'vue-apexcharts'
import axios from 'axios'
import {linearRegression, linearRegressionLine, rSquared} from 'simple-statistics'

export default {
  name: "LossChart",
  props: ["track", "tag"],
  components: {
    'apexchart': VueApexCharts,
  },
  data() {
      let corr_metrics = [
            { text: 'Min Speed', value: 'min_speed' },
            { text: 'Max Speed', value: 'max_speed' },
            { text: 'Entry Speed', value: 'entry_speed' },
            { text: 'Exit Speed', value: 'exit_speed' },
            { text: 'Min Turn Rate', value: 'min_turn_rate' },
            { text: 'Max Turn Rate', value: 'max_turn_rate' },
            { text: 'Avg Turn Rate', value: 'avg_turn_rate' },
            { text: 'Maneuver Angle', value: 'maneuver_angle' },
        ]

      return {
        metric: "min_speed",
        corr_metrics,
        segment_names: {
            T: "Tacks",
            G: "Gybes",
            B: "Bear Aways",
            D: "Douses",
        },
      }
  },
  computed: {
    tag_metrics() {
        let tag_metrics = this.track.metrics.filter((metric) => metric.label === this.tag)
        return tag_metrics
    },
    metrics() {
        let first_metric = this.tag_metrics[0]
        // only include metrics if there value is not null
        let metrics = this.corr_metrics.filter(metric => first_metric[metric.value] !== null)
        return metrics
    },
    points() {
        let points = this.tag_metrics.map((seg_metrics) => {
            let metric_value = seg_metrics[this.metric]
            return { x: metric_value, y: seg_metrics.loss_80 }
        })
        return points
    },
    regObj() {
        // Convert the array of objects back into an array of arrays
        let pointsArray = this.points.map(point => [point.x, point.y])
        return linearRegression(pointsArray)
    },
    regLine() {
        let regLine = linearRegressionLine(this.regObj)
        return regLine
    },
    r2Score() {
        let r2 = rSquared(this.points, this.regLine)
        let r2_percent = r2 * 100
        return r2_percent.toFixed(2) + "%"
    },
    regDirection() {
        if (this.regObj.m > 0) {
            return "increases"
        } else {
            return "decreases"
        }
    },
    correlated() {
        let r2 = rSquared(this.points, this.regLine)
        return r2*100 >= 1
    },
    chartSeries() {
        let minPoint = this.points.reduce((min, p) => p.x < min ? p.x : min, this.points[0].x)
        let maxPoint = this.points.reduce((max, p) => p.x > max ? p.x : max, this.points[0].x)

        let lineData = [
            { x: minPoint, y: this.regLine(minPoint) },
            { x: maxPoint, y: this.regLine(maxPoint) }
        ]
        let series = [
            {
                name: "Maneuver Loss",
                data: this.points,
                type: "scatter",
            },
            {
                name: "Correlation",
                data: lineData,
                type: "line",
            }
        ]
        return series
    },
    metric_text() {
        let metric_obj = this.metrics.find(metric => {
            return metric.value === this.metric
        })
        return metric_obj.text
    },
    chartOptions() {
        return {
            xaxis: {
                type: 'numeric',
            },
            yaxis: {
                tickAmount: 1,
                title: {
                    text: "Maneuver Loss",
                    style: {
                        color: "#000"
                    }
                },
                labels: {
                    formatter: val => val.toFixed(2)
                }
            },
            stroke: {
              dashArray: [0, 10],
              width: [5,4],
            },
            markers: {
              size: [5, 5],
              showNullDataPoints: true,
              enabled: true,
            },
            colors:['#008FFB', '#00E396'],
            legend: {
                show: false,
            },
            chart: {
                type: 'line',
                zoom: {
                    enabled: false,
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                enabledOnSeries: [0],
                shared: false,
                x: {
                    formatter: (val) => `${this.metric_text}: ${val}`
                },
                y: {
                    formatter: (val) => val.toFixed(2)
                }
            }
        }
    }

  },
}
</script>

<style>
.center {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
.chart-container {
    width: 100%;
}

</style>


TackingImprovement.vue
<template>
  <div class="windchart mt-5">
    <h1 class="is-size-4" v-if="this.tag === 'T'">Tacking Improvement</h1>
    <h1 class="is-size-4" v-if="this.tag === 'G'">Gybing Improvement</h1>
    <apexchart v-if="improvement" type="line" :options="options" :series="series">
    </apexchart>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import VueApexCharts from 'vue-apexcharts'
import axios from 'axios'
import {linearRegression, linearRegressionLine, rSquared} from 'simple-statistics'
export default {
  name: 'TackingImprovement',
  props: ['start', 'end', 'tag', 'boatclass', 'user'],
  components: {
    'apexchart': VueApexCharts,
  },
  data(){
    return {
      improvement: {
      },
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    this.getMetrics()
  },
  methods:{
    getMetrics(){
      const url = `/reports/improvement/?start=${this.start}&end=${this.end}&tag=${this.tag}&class=${this.boatclass}&user=${this.user}`
      axios.get(url).then(response => {
        this.improvement = response.data
      })
    },
    calcRegression(series){
      const coords = series.filter(point => point.y != null).map(point => {
        return [point.x.getTime(), point.y]
      })
      var lr = linearRegression(coords)
      var lrfunc = linearRegressionLine(lr)
      var rLine = []
      for (var d = new Date(this.start); d <= new Date(this.end); d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)){
        rLine.push({x: new Date(d), y: lrfunc(d.getTime())})
      }
      var rise = rLine[1].y - rLine[0].y
      var run = new Date(rLine[1].x).getTime() / 86400000 - new Date(rLine[0].x).getTime() / 86400000  // 86400000 miliseconds in a day
      return {line: rLine, percentage: ((rise / run) * 100).toFixed(2) }
    }
  },
  computed:{
    options(){
      return {
        xaxis: {
          type: 'datetime'
        },
        yaxis: {
          decimalsInFloat: 2,
          title: {
            text: 'Manuever Loss (Meters)'
          }
        },
        stroke: {
          dashArray: [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2],
          width: [5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2]
        },
        markers: {
          size: [5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          showNullDataPoints: true,
        },
        colors:['#008FFB', '#00E396', '#FEB019', '#FF4560'],
        tooltip: {
          shared: false,
          intersect: true,
        },
      }
    },
    series(){
      let light = []
      let sf  = []
      let df = []
      let windy = []
      Object.entries(this.improvement).forEach(entry => {
        light.push({x: new Date(entry[0]), y: entry[1].Light})
        sf.push({x: new Date(entry[0]), y: entry[1].Sf})
        df.push({x: new Date(entry[0]), y: entry[1].Df})
        windy.push({x: new Date(entry[0]), y: entry[1].Windy})
      })
      const lightRegression = this.calcRegression(light)
      const sfRegression = this.calcRegression(sf)
      const dfRegression = this.calcRegression(df)
      const windyRegression = this.calcRegression(windy)
      return [
        {name: 'Light', data: light, type: 'scatter'},
        {name: 'Sf', data: sf, type: 'scatter'},
        {name: 'Df', data: df, type: 'scatter'},
        {name: 'Windy', data: windy, type: 'scatter'},
        {name: `${lightRegression.percentage}%`, data: lightRegression.line, type: 'line'},
        {name: `${sfRegression.percentage}%`, data: sfRegression.line, type: 'line'},
        {name: `${dfRegression.percentage}%`, data: dfRegression.line, type: 'line'},
        {name: `${windyRegression.percentage}%`, data: windyRegression.line, type: 'line'},
    ]
    }
  },
  watch:{
    start(){
      this.getMetrics()
    },
    end(){
      this.getMetrics()
    },
    boatclass(){
      this.getMetrics()
    },
    user(){
      this.getMetrics()
    }
  }
}
</script>
<style>
  .windchart {
    max-width: 500px;
    text-align: center;
  }
</style>

I have reformatted all of the data inputs for LossChart.vue to match the inputs form TackingImprovement.vue as exactly as I can tell. I have tried changing chart options including Marker size, showNullDataPoints, enabled, etc. I have tried showing markers in the stroke... I have tried many, many iterations of the code and have not had any success. I have tried implementing the most basic, static data chart on this page and it will not load.

I can find no obvious issue with your first code. The problem might be related to the data. In any case, the solution is debugging, and for that we need a [mre]. You may consider creating a stackblitz or codesanbox for that if you think vue is an essential part of the problem.
